# import newcommand from a different file

Tags: packages

I have imported a number of packages and defined some \newcommand into my main.tex file.

How can I import all packages and \newcommand into another, separate file, which produces a different pdf document (say the supplementary information)?

Thank you
Marco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1: plain `\input`** Put the preamble into a file `mypreamble.tex` and load it with `\input` whereever you need the same definitions.

```
% mypreamble.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\mypersonalcommand{...}

% main.tex
\input{mypreamble}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}

% supplementary.tex
\input{mypreamble}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

**Solution 2: `subfiles` package** Add the line `\usepackage{subfiles}` at the end of the preamble of `main.tex` and start the supplementary files with `\documentclass[main]{subfiles}`.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\mypersonalcommand{...}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}

% supplementary.tex
\documentclass[main]{subfiles} % main refers to main.tex
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Solution 1 has the advantage of simplicity: no extra package needed, just basic (La)TeX functionality.

Solution 2 has the advantage that it will work even when `supplementary.tex` is in another directory (you just have to add the path to main, e.g. `\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}`) and the preamble also loads files. Moreover, you could use `\subfile{supplementary}` in the main document do typeset the supplementary file as part of the main file without removing the header.

In general one should avoid amassing a huge preamble file for use in all documents, as it will include many packages that are not needed for most documents, but which may interfere with each other or with a document class.

Comment: When using `\input`, is that mandatory to all the preample into the other file including `\documentclass{article}` ?

Comment: @Welgriv You can put into `mypreamble.tex` whatever you like. Just a small part of the preamble, the whole preamble with/without `\documentclass`. `\input` reads the file and treats its contents as if you had written it at the place of the `\input`.

Comment: ok thanks. Apologies for the stupid question, I just figured out my bug was not at all coming from this...